# squirrel sql search all tables and fields - or any software

Tags: sql

I want to find a string like "txstate" in a wordpress (or magento, etc) database and it could be in any table or field.

Can this be done in SQuirreLSQL?  I have searched on this and not getting answers.  I have a MacBook Pro, so if you can't do it in Squirrel, perhaps there is another client that might do it.  I haven't found any way to do it in Sequel Pro for example.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this in SQuirreLSQL, is to select all tables and then right click and select Scripts -> Create Data Script.

This will create a script with insert statements for all your tables.
You can then search in the script for the text you are looking for.